# Why does zsh expand globs for me in a bash script using GNU parallel?

Tags: bash, zsh, gnu-parallel

In a bash script, I have a command using rsync:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash -e
...
parallel rsync --exclude '*to?be?deleted*' ... 
    --files-from some_file /auto $instance_ip:/somewhere_else/
```

According to rsync's documentation, their `--exclude` field has a *different style of pattern matching*.

When I run this in a bash terminal, it works fine.

However, running this on zsh gives me an error because zsh tries to expand this literal string I'm trying to pass in:

```
zsh:1: no matches found: *to?be?deleted*
```

This should **not** happen. Why is zsh even expanding my globs in my *bash* script in the first place? Is there some settings on my zsh that I can set to make the two behave the same way? I don't want to develop in zsh and deploy to an environment with bash and have to behave in different ways.

I am using oh-my-zsh's plugins:

```
plugins=(
  git
  colored-man-pages
  zsh-autosuggestions
  zsh-syntax-highlighting
)
```

Specifically, with this set of commands it fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash -e
find . -name '*filelist' | parallel -j10 rsync --exclude "*to?be?deleted*" testing somewhere_else:/some/where/else
```

But with rsync's command by itself, it doesn't break.

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: `$ bash my_script.sh`

Comment: Then it's especially surprising. What's the `...` in your script, and do you get the same thing without that?

Comment: well, the `...` is _quite_ long, but it's setting up a cloud instance and doing some preprocessing. I am trying to `rsync` over the files. I tried doing a simple `rsync` and it worked. I have sent over a MVCE in my question :)

Comment: You quoted the pattern in the bash script, but all the extra arguments to `parallel` are passed to *another* shell, minus the quotes that `bash` has already stripped.

Comment: BTW, `printf -v cmd '%q ' rsync --exclude "*to?be?deleted*" testing somewhere_else:/some/where/else` will put a correctly-quoted command in the variable named `cmd`, such that you could pass it as `"$cmd"`.

Comment: BTW, if you want something with less magic than GNU parallel, you might evaluate whether `xargs -P10` is sufficient to your use case. It's far less featureful, but whether that's a benefit or a drawback is open to interpretation. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the heads up :) I didn't know about `xargs` until you mentioned it. I will keep it in mind for future uses(I am executing legacy code and not sure if their decision to use parallel is particular enough that replacing with `xargs` will break anything)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem on versions > 20140722. Which version of GNU Parallel are you using?

Comment: I am using gnu parallel 20130622.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parallel` is starting an instance of your login shell using a string consisting of the arguments it is passed. Your `bash` script strips the quotes before passing the argument, so parallel is executing the equivalent of

```
zsh -c "rsync --exclude *to?be?deleted* testing somewhere_else:/some/where/else"
```

in which the pattern is *not* quoted. To prevent this, pass a single string as an argument to `parallel`:

```
... | parallel -j10 'rsync --exclude "*to?be?deleted*" testing somewhere_else:/some/where/else'
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's fair to blame bash for `parallel` concatenating arguments together to form a string, and then passing that string to a shell. That's bad practice when *anyone* does it, even if done all-too-often (as by the likes of `ssh`).

Comment: I'm not blaming `parallel`; I don't see what else it *could* do. I'm just pointing out that's the reason for `zsh` trying to expand what was thought to be a quoted pattern.

Comment: (Or did I miss a deleted comment?)

Comment: I see. That's quite dangerous for `parallel` to be doing that, I have changed it into an entire quote. Thanks :)

Comment: Color me a purist -- my view is that it's blatantly wrong for `ssh` (or `parallel` or any other program) to implicitly run `"${SHELL:-sh}" -c`, and that a program given an argv to be used to invoke another piece of software should pass it through to an execv-style call literally and unmodified, rather than try to build a string out of it. So in those places where parallel makes guarantees to the user that *require* invoking a shell without `sh` being passed as an argument, my position is that it's intolerably bad design.

Comment: Er, I should have said I'm not blaming `bash`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's wrong for parallel. With ssh, it's unavoidable, because ssh can't avoid going through the remote shell.

Comment: @Gilles, in the SSH case, it's bad design at the protocol level rather than the implementation layer -- the protocol should have been designed to allow a literal argv to be passed over the wire, rather than being designed to pass a single string. Granted, that's harder to fix, but it's a design flaw nonetheless.

Comment: "parallel is starting an instance of your login shell". This is typically not the case when using version > 20140822. Instead it starts the same shell that GNU Parallel is started from. So it is important to know which version OP is using.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the GNU Parallel utility. Even though it looks like you're passing it a program to run with arguments, what it's actually doing is to concatenate the arguments and pass them to a shell.

Furthermore Parallel either runs the same shell that you ran `parallel` from, or chooses the shell based on the `SHELL` environment variable (which is questionable since this environment variable is also used by terminal emulators to decide which interactive shell to run). Either way, this is why it's picking zsh rather than sh. You'd have the same problem with a shell that's compatible with sh (bash, dash, ksh, …), but more rarely: sh leaves patterns alone if they don't match anything, so with sh your script would work as long as there was no file matching `*to?be?deleted*` in the current directory.

The solution is given in the manual, but it's a bit hard to find: pass the `-q` option. The manual has a very long chapter on quoting which you can ignore 99% of the time: just pass `-q` unless you meant to run a *shell script* and not a *command*. Furthermore, you should use the full path to the command, otherwise parallel might invoke a shell builtin or even a function (if your shell is bash). Also, set `SHELL` to `/bin/sh`, because even with `-q`, Parallel runs a shell, and assumes that it's compatible with sh (I think zsh is sufficiently compatible, but I'm not completely sure.). See also [a similar question on Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364129/prevent-gnu-parallel-from-splitting-quoted-arguments)

```
SHELL=/bin/sh parallel -q -j10 "$(command -v rsync)" --exclude "*to?be?deleted*" testing somewhere_else:/some/where/else
```

(Yes, the manual discourages you from using `-q`, but it's wrong. I've argued with the author about this before.)

Comment: This was a very comprehensive answer. Thank you :) I bet this has happened to countless amount of people using a different shell than bash and wondering why their bash script invokes zsh for example.

Comment: It's not even clear what `-q` *does*, based on its description. Does it add a layer of quotes around each of the words, like `'rsync' '--exclude' '*to?be?deleted*' 'testing' 'somewhere...'`?

Comment: @chepner Good point, it passes a shell and quotes the string. [Stéphane Chazelas tried to explain to the author how shells work, but in vain](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parallel/2015-05/msg00005.html).

Comment: @OneRaynyDay [Indeed, it's come up before.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quoting+gnu-parallel)

Comment: @chepner `-q` quotes the command and arguments. The actual way of quoting depends on the shell, but for most shells it is \-quoted. `-vv` will show what it actually being run.

Comment: "unless you meant to run a shell script and not a command. " ... and not a pipeline, and not a list, and not compound command, and not redirections, and not variable assignments. Shorter: It is only if you want to run what the Bash manual calls Simple Commands without redirections and variable assignments that you can use `-q`.

Comment: @OleTange Pipelines, lists, compound commands and redirections are shell concepts. But you do indirectly make a point that it's not quite what I wrote: even `-q` doesn't protect against shell overrides, since it actually runs a shell simple command and not an external command.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel version < 20140722 uses `$SHELL`. Later versions try to detect which shell GNU Parallel is started from, and use that shell instead. Details on the detection can be found in `man parallel_design` ([`Which shell to use`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_design.html#Which-shell-to-use)). Here it is also explained why GNU Parallel always runs the commands in a shell ([`Always running commands in a shell`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_design.html#Always-running-commands-in-a-shell)).

If you not want the shell to expand special chars, you can use `-q`.
However, the command must be a simple command (see `man bash`) without redirections and without variable assignments. This
will quote the command line and arguments so special characters are
not interpreted by the shell.

Comment: Thank you for this. I appreciate the investigation. I cannot necessarily update the gnu parallel on this machine due to organizational policies, but it will be noted for future uses.

Comment: If you are allowed to run your own scripts, then you can either use `--embed` (>=20180322) or do a personal installation.